# Parametrize schema name when creating DB tables with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, database, oop, sqlalchemy, database-schema

I have a module `db_models.py` where I define my tables like so:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Date
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()


class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mytable'
    __table_args__ = {'comment': 'test comment'}

    my_date = Column(Date, primary_key=True)
    my_word = Column(String(12))


class MyOtherTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'myothertable'
    __table_args__ = {'comment': 'test comment'}

    my_date = Column(Date, primary_key=True)
    my_song = Column(String(96))
```

Then in another module I import `Base` and there I need to create the tables in an arbitrary schema. So I'm trying to change schema for each table in `Base.metadata` like so (`my_session` is an existing DB session):

```py
from db_models import Base

Base.metadata.schema = 'test-schema'
Base.metadata.create_all(my_session.get_bind())
```

This is not working and the tables are created in the default schema. How do I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this code works:

```py
for table in Base.metadata.tables.values():
    table.schema = 'test-schema'
Base.metadata.create_all(my_session.get_bind())
```

But I'm not sure if that's a good way to do this.